# WSL2 does not display GUI apps consistently

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When starting a graphical application from WSL2 (Ubuntu), it is not rendering properly most of the time:
[image: bad emacs]

As I move the mouse around, this "bad image" *(which looks to me like a second rendering?)* will disappear and I can briefly see the "good" version.
I was able to get it working once- I think I exited {wsl} and then restarted it. But then I had to reboot the laptop and since then there has been no recovery that I can find.

Has anyone seen this and have suggestions?

Thanks!

.Tim

Comment: Unfortunately, that looks like either a rendering bug or a GPU hardware malfunction. If it happens only with WSL2, it's probably a bug; but you should try some native Windows program that puts some significant load on your GPU and see if you see any graphics errors then. If you do, and your laptop is still under warranty, contact the vendor for possible warranty service or replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after I upgraded wsl to 2.0.14. What helped in my case was simply running some updates.

1. Update Windows graphic drivers to the latest (reboot if required)
2. From Ubuntu prompt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

3. Then from Windows Elevated Command Prompt (or PowerShell):

```
wsl --shutdown
```

This problem is quite common actually. You can find some more ideas here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1148
- https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1130

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions! I had this issue before Christmas and it just popped up again today. Running `wsl -shutdown` fixed it again for now. It started happening after doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it obviously needed a restart afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue - but using RHEL rather than Ubuntu.

In my case I had to install the very latest video drivers to fix this.  And when corporate IT "upgraded" me to older drivers, I had to reinstall the latest drivers -- thus reverifying that this was the issue.

As long as I stay on the latest drivers I see no issues whatsoever along these lines.